# Matlab: Out of memory error during multiplication operation

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

```
 R = randn(960,d); creates a matrix of random numbers.
```

I have another matrix `X` of dimension `1000000 by 960`. When I am doing the operation

```
B = (X*R >=0) ;
```

I get the error

```
Error using  * 
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

for `d = 4096`. But, there is no error for `d < 4096` esp. `d = [32 64  128 256 512 1024    2048    ]` gives no problem except for cases of `d>4096`. X  has data elements that are in single precision format.

Typing `memory` gives

```
Maximum possible array:              15663 MB (1.642e+010 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     15663 MB (1.642e+010 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:                4706 MB (4.935e+009 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):                8151 MB (8.547e+009 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

I have no idea how I can solve this problem. I am running Matlab 64 bit 2011b version on Windows 64 bit OS with 8 GB RAM and i7 processor. Please help!

Comment: clear your Workspace by typing "clear all" in the Command Window and then re-type `memory`. What's the output?

Comment: Just do the math! With a size of 1000000*4096 you need 31250 MB to store the result of the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a little math comes handy.
In Matlab 1 element in single precision occupies 4 Bytes in memory whereas a 1 element in double precision occupies 8 Bytes.
The size of `X` (single precision) is 1000000*960 elements, 4 Bytes each, for a total of 3.84 GB.
The size of `R` (double precision) is 960*4096 elements, 8 Bytes each, for a total of 0.0315 GB.

Now the problem is the product `X*R`, that must be preallocated and then evaluated in order to feed the logical indexing on `B`. The matrix `X*R` will have size 1000000*4096 and by supposing such matrix is in single precision (to my knowledge, the product between a double and a single is a single as well), it will occupy something like 16GB. This will most certainly clog both the physical and the virtual memory (and also 16GB is greater than the `Maximum possible array` size from your memory command).

Comment: I see, thank you for the reply. Could you please suggest the solution for a similar problem? I am getting out of memory error for transpose operation of the result of another matrix whose dimension is is 960 by 960or higher order square matrix. Is the physical memory restriction also causing error in both transpose and multiplication?

Comment: I have increased the virtual memory size to 16GB (after going through suggestions under Mathworks), yet the problem persists.

Comment: A 960*960 matrix occupies something like 7MB (if in double precision) so it shouldn't be that much of a problem for a PC like yours. Try to cleanup from the workspace the variables you don't use, especially now that you're working with big matrices. Run 1 task at a time, let's say perform the transpose, cleanup unnecessary variables from the workspace and then proceed with the following task. Have you also rebooted your PC after changing the virtual memory size? I reckon Windows will be happier if you reboot.

Comment: Depending on what your code flow is, you might want as well considering saving the results to disk (also in .mat format, that is pretty straightforward), cleaning up the Workspace and then proceed with the next calculation/task.